# The derivation in a ring: $d(\pi)$

Tags: ring-theory

Let us consider the usual definition of the derivation on a commutative ring $A$:

> A map $d:A\to A$ satisfying $d(a+b)=d(a)+d(b)$ and the Leibniz rule $d(a\cdot b)=a\cdot d(b)+b\cdot d(a)$.

Now, let $A=\mathbb{R}$. It is clear that $d(1)=0$ as $d(1)=d(1\cdot 1)=1\cdot d(1)+1\cdot d(1)$ and it follows that $d(q)=0$ for every rational $q$. But what for transcendental numbers, say $\pi$? Leibniz rule does not imply zero value of its derivation!
(I intentionally don't want to introduce here a B-derivation on a B-algebra A: of course, it is a different situation.)

Comment: What makes you think $d(\pi)$ can only be one thing? There are probably multiple $d$ satisfying the given property.

Comment: The derivative of every algebraic number is also $0$. But since $\pi$ is trascendental, you can define it as you wish.